# Long pressed menu in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

how to make this top bar menu when we do a long press on a card or container.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your card widget with *InkWell* or *GestureDetector* both have longPress, then you pass a call back to your view to show the menu.

```
Color _colorFilterTile = Colors.transparent;
    InkWell(
      onLongPress: (){
        //call function
        setState(() {
          _colorFilterTile= Colors.green.withOpacity(0.5);
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        color: _colorFilterTile,
        child: ...,
      ),
    )
```

Comment: but it is very small. I need it to cover the width of the screen and also change the color that I don't know how to do.

Comment: to cover the width just wrap the tile item, to change the color need to set a state to change the color. see the edited answer

Comment: to be more precise with the color try with a Stack for example that part is up to you how you wanna the efect